# Where does Kubernetes log the output of "docker run"?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am debugging [a Kubernetes cluster which deploys Docker containers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46522474/51197).

How can I see the results and exit code of `docker run` executed by Kubernetes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kubernetes does not execute `docker run` command, it works with an API, usualy via default docker endpoint `unix:///var/run/docker.sock`

Comment: Thanks. Where would be the output of that, for debugging a deployment?